# Photon emmision from an accelerating particle

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, charge, quantum-electrodynamics, quantization

How does an accelerating charged particle emit a quantized photon?

Quantization of light makes sense to me if we were talking about vibrating charged particles or electron orbitals. But what about a linearly accelerating proton? The wave model of light would describe the photon emission (like a boat making waves in water) but how is that quantized? Would the proton accelerate for some specific amount of time, emitting no photon, and then randomly a single photon fires off?

If my question is flawed or I am missing something please let me know. Any information would help!

Answer (score 2):

The process is similar to what is known as [*Bremsstrahlung*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) (from German, meaning *braking radiation*), which happens when a particle is decelerating. In this case particle will not be emitting a single photon, but a continuous stream of *soft photons*, i.e. photons of very low energy. Moreover, since in QFT "particles" (i.e., fermions) and "field" (i.e., bosons) are treated on the same footing, one cannot really model consistently a situation where the particle accelerates or decelerates for an unknown reason - so the analysis is usuallyt more specific, such as a particle passing near a nucleus and chnaging its trajectory.

The treatments can be found in most QFT texts, such as Mandl&Shaw, Peskin&Schroeder, etc.

Comment: Appreciate the answer and I have done some more research. I watched MIT YouTube lectures about Bremstrahlung and the professor talked about how a cyclotron would emit x-rays each time the charged particle would change directions. How does quantization occur here? Is an x-ray of discrete energy emitted randomly, or is there a deeper process that would allow an experimenter to predict the exact energy of the emitted photon?